# Is it possible to for one widget's client side trigger to fire a second widget's server side trigger

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a checkbox with a server side trigger on the value change event.  Whenever I check/uncheck that box, I can see the round trip in the logs.

I have a button configured so that when I click the button, it checks the box.  It checks it fine, but I would expect that the value change trigger to invoke.  It does not.

Is this documented to not work and I can't find it?   Am I setting it up wrong?  A bug?

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var serverHandler = app.createServerHandler('myClickHandler');
  var cb = app.createCheckBox().addValueChangeHandler(serverHandler).setName('box');
  var button = app.createButton('Press me');
  var clientHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(cb).setValue(true);
  button.addClickHandler(clientHandler);
  app.add(button).add(cb);
  return app;
}

function myClickHandler(e) {
  Logger.log(e);
  return UiApp.getActiveApplication();
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per [CheckBox.setValue() method documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/check-box#setValue(Boolean)):

> Sets whether the CheckBox should be checked. ***Does not fire any events
>   if the value changes as a result of this call.***

You will need to add a server handler to your button to achieve what you want.

Comment: Right.  However, the setValue() I'm calling is actually on the ClientHandler, not the CheckBox.  I don't know what the actual implementation is, but I would not be surprised if deep down in the guts, ClientHandler arranges for cb.setValue(true) to be called.

However, CheckBox does have the setValue(true, true) option which would fire the event.  I was hoping that a ClientHandler would cause THAT method to be invoked. Of if there was a way to make that happen in the ClientHandler.

I was hoping to avoid having to write multiple server handlers to do the same thing.